# Extracting visual studio theme?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, themes, save

I want to save my theme out of visual studio so that if(when) i need to reformat my computer my theme is available for use. How can i do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Tools > Import and Export settings > Export Selected Settings**

VS theme is set in customize options - which on the export dialog is filed under 'Options'.

To save your entire current theme, ensure that the whole Options node is checked.

Comment: In `C:\Users\William\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings` are your current settings. You don't even have to hit "Export"

Answer (score 24):

If you want to only save the theme, On Visual Studio 2012*, you can go to: Tools->Customize Colors. Hover over your custom theme and click on "Edit Theme" (pencil icon). On the top bar you will find the option "Export Theme"

I think this could be the same on VS2010 if you have Visual Studio Color Theme Editor installed

Comment: This is the real answer for those using the Visual Studio Themes plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "Customize Color", you can select the theme you want to export, press "Edit", after that in the top of the settings you can find an icon of a pallet of colors that is used to export the current theme.